# Nikon D3300 with AF-P VR wont focus

Tags: nikon, autofocus, camera-settings

I bought Nikon D3300 with stock lens AF-P 18-55 VR and it worked great for about an year. But during our last trip focus stopped working. Keep in mind I am very casual photographer.

I found this Q&A [What should I do when my Nikon AF-S lens won't auto focus?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20624/what-should-i-do-when-my-nikon-af-s-lens-wont-auto-focus) but nothing helped.
What I tried so far:

- Focus Mode set to AF-A, I can make blurry photos when set to M
- Rangefinder is ON
- Detach and reattach lenses
- Cleaned lens
- Charge battery fully
- I do not have button on lens M<>A, its only set in menu
- AE-L/AF-L button is not pressed - when pressed I can make blurry photos again

I am not sure how to make this - https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/47688/71642 I tried to twist it but it does nothing.

Unfortunately I have no other lens to try.

One interested thing is, when I try focus manually, it just doesn't work. I mean when I set focus mode to M, rotating focus lens with hand doesn't change focus at all. But maybe  it doesnt work this way?

Any ideas?

Comment: check out this compatibility chart: http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/compatibility-lens.htm Ken mentions that D3300 need latest firmware for AF-P lenses to work

Comment: @aaaaaa I thought the same thing, but note that OP said that D3300+lens worked great for about a year. So obviously OP's camera had the required firmware.

Comment: The lens were bundled with camera, so I doubt its firmware issue. I can try update it but as noted, it worked before fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with RMA and they replaced main board in lens.